# Aggregating the columns having list as values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

I have a dataframe which have 3 columns with one of the columns having a list of values.

I want aggregate that list into single list when doing groupby.

DataFrame looks like this

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['A','B'] | Hi |
| 2 | NaN | Po |
| 1 | ['B','C'] | Yo |
| 2 | ['D','E'] | Yup |

Now I want my dataframe to look like this

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ['A','B','C'] | ['Hi','Yo'] |
| 2 | ['D','E'] | ['Po','Yup'] |

I used the agrregating function with list past as parameter but I am getting the result like this

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [['A','B'],['B','C']] | ['Hi','Yo'] |
| 2 | ['D','E'] | ['Po','Yup'] |

Can anyone please help on how to get this result??

Comment: Could you please provide a code?

Comment: df.groupby('C1').agg(list)

Comment: Sorry, I was not precise, code example where you are trying to do this. Ideally containing the dataframe. It just makes it much easier to replicate what you are currently trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use groupby and and agg to apply different functions to each column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'C2': [['A', 'B'], None, ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']],
                   'C3': ['Hi', 'Po', 'Yo', 'Yup']})

df = df.groupby('C1').agg({'C2': lambda x: np.unique([value for value in x.dropna()]),
                                   'C3': list})
df
```

Output:

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [A, B, C] | [Hi, Yo] |
| 2 | [D, E] | [Po, Yup] |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

(df.groupby('C1', as_index=False)
   .agg({'C2': lambda g: np.unique(np.r_[tuple(g.dropna())].ravel()),
         'C3': list
        })
)
```

Output:

```
   C1         C2         C3
0   1  [A, B, C]   [Hi, Yo]
1   2     [D, E]  [Po, Yup]
```

Comment: @BrownBatman was there any issue with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider to explode before the groupby?

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'C1':[1, 2, 1, 2],
     'C2': [['A', 'B'], '', ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E']],
     'C3': ['Hi', 'Po', 'Yo', 'Yup']})
```

## Explode

```py
df1 = df.explode('C2')
print(df1)
```

output

```bash
   C1 C2   C3
0   1  A   Hi
0   1  B   Hi
1   2      Po
2   1  B   Yo
2   1  C   Yo
3   2  D  Yup
3   2  E  Yup
```

## Group by and unique

```py
df1.groupby('C1')\
  .agg(
    {"C2": "unique",
     "C3": "unique"})
```

output

```bash
           C2         C3
C1                      
1   [A, B, C]   [Hi, Yo]
2    [, D, E]  [Po, Yup]
```

## Full code

```py
df_out = df.explode('C2')\
  .groupby('C1')\
  .agg(
    {"C2": "unique",
     "C3": "unique"})
```

Now you can eventually remove the `''` or nan.